# Https access authentication workd but not normal

Tags: http, web, https, authorization

I would like to login automatically to a webpage secured with http basic access.

I tried to use a simple link to login in the basic access auth:

```
https://user:pw@example.com.
```

In Firefox it's working really good. But in other browsers like Chrome, it logs in but first, the browser displays only the website structure.

When I load the one more (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>) all is displayed as expected...

Does anybody know why this happens and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you perhaps add some more details? Is this related to software you've written, or is it a third-party system?

Comment: Do you want to pass username and password in URL for HTTP Basic Auth? If yes, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43797979/pass-username-and-password-in-url-for-http-basic-auth/43829387#43829387

Comment: it's a simply website

Comment: I mean, do you put `https://user:pw@example.com` into the browser's address bar and try to open it?

Comment: yes. in the browser to autologin