# curl POST works but ionic this.http.post doesn't

Tags: http, curl, ionic2, xmlhttprequest, couchdb

I am struggling to get an ionic `this.http.post` to work.

If I use this curl in my terminal it works great:

```
curl -v -X POST \
  https://myuser-name:ijF3Ui7VYVbbSejmwsnVVo@appdb.mysite.com:5984/_session \
  -d 'name=app&password=ijF3Ui7VYVbbSejmwsnVVo'
```

It gives me the following output:

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 37.1.96.50...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to app.mysite.com (37.1.96.49) port 5984 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Server certificate: app.mysite.com
* Server certificate: COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
* Server certificate: COMODO RSA Certification Authority
* Server auth using Basic with user 'myuser-name'
> POST /_session HTTP/1.1
> Host: app.mysite.com:5984
> Authorization: Basic cDpkTUQySzg0a2lqRjNVaTdWWVZiYlNlam13c25WVm8=
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 52
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 52 out of 52 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Set-Cookie: AuthSession=ZWhzLWFwcDo1OUFENThGRjruBtcPzHcqc1sC9WXrcWI7R27_Mg; Version=1;  Secure; Path=/; HttpOnly
< Server: CouchDB/1.6.1 (Erlang OTP/18)
< Date: Mon, 04 Sep 2017 13:45:35 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 43
< Cache-Control: must-revalidate
< 
{"ok":true,"name":null,"roles":["_admin"]}
* Connection #0 to host app.mysite.com left intact
```

My ionic POST code looks like this:

```js
  login(callerName:string):any
  // Make sure we have a CouchDB session so that PouchDB can access the CouchDB database
  {
    console.log('Authentication: login(): Login function called from ' + callerName);

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      let credentials = {
        name: COUCHDB_USER,
        password: COUCHDB_PASSWORD
      };

      let result = {
        success: false,
        data: []
      };

      console.log('Authentication: login(): credentials = ' + JSON.stringify(credentials));

      // NOTE:
      //
      // If POST is called with COUCHDB_SERVER with no auth in the url I get the error: Response with status: 401 Unauthorized for URL: https://app.mysite.com:5984/_session"
      //    
      // If POST is called with COUCHDB_SERVER WITH auth in url I get the error: Response with status: 0 for URL: null
      //    This 'might' mean:
      //        Timeout from server
      //        Request not sent
      //        Requesting an unreachable url
      //        ...
      //    This WORKS with curl in terminal
      //
      // With auth in url: https://myuser-name:ijF3Ui7VYVbbSejmwsnVVo@app.mysite:5984/_session
      // Without auth in url: https://app.mysite.com:5984/_session
      //
      this.http.post(COUCHDB_SERVER + '/_session', JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers: headers})
        .subscribe(res => {
            var details = res.json();
            console.log('Authentication: login(): SuperLogin successful login: res = ' + JSON.stringify(details));

            result.success = true;
            result.data = details;
            resolve(result);
          },
          (err) => {
            console.log('Authentication: login(): Login failed err = ' + err);

            let details = err.json();
            result.success = false;
            result.data = details;
            resolve(result);
          });
    });
  }
```

If I try the POST in ionic with no auth in the url I get a sensible error message:

```
Response with status: 401 Unauthorized for URL: https://app.mysite.com:5984/_session"
```

But if I add auth to the url I get an error message that doesn't tell me what the problem is:

```
Response with status: 0 for URL: null
```

I can't work out why it works with curl but not within ionic http.post.

I have the same problem whether I run `ionic serve` or I run the app on an iPhone.

**UPDATE**

I have run the ionic App in Chrome and now have a better error:

```
error: "unauthorized", reason: "Authentication required."
```

So it is clear I am not getting the POST request correct but can't see why.

Comment: Your HTTP request sent by curl and ionic are different. The `Content-Type` of HTTP request sent by curl is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the one sent by ionic is `application/json`. Can you make them consistent and try again?

Comment: @shaochuancs Unfortunately I still get the same error. I updated my question to show that on Chrome I am now getting a sensible error: error: "unauthorized", reason: "Authentication required." So clearly I am not forming my POST request properly

Comment: yes...you have converted it to a string by `JSON.stringify(credentials)`. But it's not necessary, just pass `credential` as the second parameter of `this.http.post` and it should be OK. Please refer to https://angular.io/guide/http for official example.

Comment: @shaochuancs I have removed the JSON.stringify but am still getting the same error.

Comment: Have you added auth to the URL (`myusername:ijF3Ui7VYVbbSejmwsnVVo@`)? Don't add it. It works in curl but browser will ignore it.

Comment: @shaochuancs yes the url looks like this: https://myuser-name:ijF3Ui7VYVbbSejmwsnVVo@app.mysite.com:5984/_session

Comment: Please don't pass username and password in URL. It only works in curl but won't work in browser. Please check my previous answer for another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43797979/pass-username-and-password-in-url-for-http-basic-auth/43829387#43829387

Comment: Actually, it's unnecessary to pass username&password in URL -- anyway, the credential would be passed in request body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authentication failed in ionic because the usage of `this.http.post` is incorrect: the second parameter should be HTTP request body object (JSON, the `credential` object), not a string. Please refer to https://angular.io/guide/http for example.

The code to send HTTP request would be:

```
this.http.post(COUCHDB_SERVER + '/_session', credentials, {headers: headers})...
```

*It works in curl, but not in ionic* -- That's because the `Content-Type` of the HTTP request sent by curl is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and curl's syntax is correct.

*Shall I add auth to the URL?* -- I guess it means the `myuser-name:ijF3Ui7VYVbbSejmwsnVVo@` part in the URL. The answer is No: It works in curl (add `Authorization` header in request) but it won't work in browser, please check [Pass username and password in URL for HTTP Basic Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43797979/pass-username-and-password-in-url-for-http-basic-auth/43829387#43829387) for details.

Update: It seems Basic authentication is forced in CouchDB. In order to satisfy it, `Authorization` header can be added manually in HTTP request:

```
headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + window.btoa(username + ':' + password))
```

Comment: I have removed the auth from the url and my http.post is now as per your example. I am now getting an "Authentication Required" modal popping up.

Comment: I read the Pass username post which was very useful thanks. It explains a lot that I should know but didn't. Especially why curl works but Postman doesn't. Interestingly I can't get Postman to work with my POST call either. Maybe this is connected?

Comment: @BillNoble It seems Basic authentication is enabled in your CouchDB. In order to satisfy the "Authentication Required" modal pop up, you can add an `Authorization` header in ionic code manually. Such as: `headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + window.btoa(username + ':' + password))`

Comment: Ok I now have the following headers but I am still getting a 401 unauthorised and an Authentication Required modal:
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + window.btoa(COUCHDB_USER + ':' + COUCHDB_PASSWORD));

Comment: @BillNoble you don't need to add `headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');`. The credential is passed as `application/json` and you have already defined it in `headers`

Comment: @BillNoble What is your CouchDB version? In my CouchDB 2.1.0, once `application/json` request to `/_session` is sent, it is 200 OK, no auth part in URL, no `Authorization` header in request, no `WWW-Authenticate` header in response, it just works. I verified with Postman -- can you explain how your Postman can't work?

Comment: Great! I have removed the x-www-form-urlencoded and my this.http.post works! Thank you so much for perservering with this I can't thank you enough. I am still getting a CouchDB authorisation modal popping up when running ionic serve though. Looks like PouchDB isn't picking up the cookie returned by _session.

Comment: @BillNoble you are welcome. It seems Basic authentication is forced in your case. Anyway, you can add `Authorization` header in request to prevent modal popup.